# Make MathJax obey max-width property

Tags: css, latex, mathjax

I have a paragraph with a bunch of math in it, and I have a rule setting all paragraphs to have a max-width of `30em`. I think that inline math is following this rule, but the display math generated just keeps going to the right. Is there any way to force it to wrap around when it hits the max-width?

In order to make the point clear, I've attached an image showing what happens when it's set to `20em`.

```
#infoDiv p {
    max-width: 20em;
}
```

[image]

Here's my MathJax configuration:

```
MathJax.Hub.Config({
    extensions: ["tex2jax.js","TeX/AmsMath.js","TeX/AMSsymbols.js"],
    jax: ["input/TeX","output/HTML-CSS"],
    tex2jax: {
        inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ["\\(","\\)"] ],
        displayMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ["\\[","\\]"] ],
        processEscapes: true,
        processEnvironments: true
    },
    displayAlign: "left",
    skipTags: ["script","noscript","style","textarea"],
    "HTML-CSS": { availableFonts: ["TeX"], linebreaks: { automatic: true } },
    SVG: { linebreaks: { automatic: true } }
});
```

**EDIT:** Here's the part which isn't staying within the max-width:

```
To see this, let $M = [m_{ij}]$, $\mathbf{u} = (u_1, \ldots, u_n)$ and $\mathbf{v} = (v_1, \ldots, v_n)$. Then
\begin{align*}
(M\mathbf{u})\cdot v &= \begin{bmatrix}
m_{11} u_1 + m_{12}u_2 + \cdots + m_{1n}u_n
\\ \vdots
\\ m_{n1} u_1 + m_{n2}u_2 + \cdots + m_{nn}u_n
\end{bmatrix} \cdot \mathbf{v}
\\ &= v_1 ( m_{11} u_1 + m_{12} u_2 + \cdots + m_{1n} u_n ) + \cdots
\\ &+ v_n ( m_{n1} u_1 + m_{n2} u_2 + \cdots + m_{nn} u_n ) \tag{def of $\cdot$ and comm. of $\cdot$ in $\mathbb{R}$}
\end{align*}
```

Comment: Please show the relevant code for the expression. In a simple test, MathJax wrapped a display equation normally, as expected, to make it fit into the width set on the contained element.

Comment: Did you give it a max-width or a width? Maybe that's part of the problem.. I'll post the code above.

Comment: I tested with `max-width` and with a simple long polynomial. It seems that the problem is with the `align` environment.

Comment: Yeah that's what I figured. Thanks for confirming. I wonder if this would count as a bug..

Comment: I suspect it's a bug in MathJax's linebreaking algorithm. It seems related to https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/596

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at this, @Peter.

Comment: Did you end up figuring this? I am also using the aligned environment in Markdown and have the same issue with long equations when viewed on mobile. Any display mode gives me this issue not just aligned

Comment: @Corel I don't believe I figured out a solution for this, sorry, though it looks like the related issue pointed out by Peter was fixed in 2015, so you might want to try updating your version.